# Посоветуйте видеоуроки или книги для изучения PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, книги

Всем привет! Посоветуйте книги, туториалы, видеоуроки для изучения PHP Laravel

Comment: Если это дубликат, перенесите книги по Laravel и другим фреймворкам в основную ветку, если посчитаете нужным.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. для версии 5, для ознакомления можно посмотреть. хоть и версия устарела, но Афанасьев очень доходчиво умеет объяснять  [Дмитрий Афанасьев - Laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJPOkWFLPs0&list=PLoonZ8wII66h7pF6CFPzK3pVhTWo3DL9G)
2. версия 5.4 [Станислав Бойко](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jpLSD0vqrA&list=PL8jSdafHd96yJNUtOIc8AjPnuDnoyIGWh)
3. Хорошая статья по Laravel для чайников - 
   [Laravel. Установка, настройка, создание и деплой приложения](https://habrahabr.ru/post/197454/)
4. Хороший сайт по изучению, подробно всё разжовывает - 
   [Основы Laravel 5](https://laravel.ru/posts/398)

Желаю успехов и терпения!

Comment: Спасибо брат по клавиатуре!)